# How to loop specific data?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a admin panel and I want to display how many users visited the website in the past seven days. It's not efficient to loop every data in the database and then display some of them. I only want to loop the data from the past seven days.

I do have the user information as a D-M-Y format.

I did something like this but I don't think it's correct.

```
$TimeStamp       = time();
$OneWeek = 604800;
$FoundOneWeekAgo = $TimeStamp - $OneWeek;

$Query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM new_user');
$Query->execute();
$Count = $Query->rowCount();
$QueryRecords = $Query->fetchAll();


foreach ($QueryRecords as $Users) {
    
    $UserDate = $Users["Date"];
    $DataTimeStamp = strtotime($UserDate);

}

if ($DataTimeStamp >= $FoundOneWeekAgo) {
    //Don't know what to do here
}
```

Help me out I'm open to your thoughts about it.

Main idea : found the users visited at the specific date.

Comment: You should use filter in your SQL query to reduce the records

Comment: Something like `SELECT count(*) FROM new_user where Date >= now() - interval 7 day` would give you count of uses in the past 7 days

Comment: ...actually... `D-M-Y` is not MySQL datetime format, so step 1 is fix `date` column to be a `date` or `datetime`. Then you can easily do this with SQL.

Comment: `as a D-M-Y format`..this is a fundamental mistake. Store dates in `date` or `datetime` field, then you can do SQL filtering on them easily. These types exist for good reasons - please use them. (N.B. You can convert the format every time you select the data, but it may slow down your query.)

Comment: Thank you for all the information and warnings but it's not my database it's one of my new clients so... don't wanna waste too much time with messing his database. I asked him why did you do it like this and the answer was `because it's easy to read` I'll just deal with it

Comment: Well they shouldn't be reading directly from the database anyway ordinarily lol. I'd normally expect only the developer would need to look directly at the raw data. Everything else surely is done via an application or at least a reporting tool (where formatting can be applied to dates as needed)? I'd press them to redesign it really otherwise it'll just keep giving you hassle.

Comment: I'll try that but I have no hope... he is a ...cheap guy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve only specific data from the database.

```
Select * from new_user where date >= DATE(NOW() -INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

If you have data in `d-m-y` format,you can do-

```
Select * from new_user where date >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW() -INTERVAL 7 DAY),"%d-%m-%y")
```

Comment: How can I loop this? I did tried to loop with ```foreach($QueryRecords as $Users) {
    echo $Users["id"];
}``` But didn't get anything? No error No output

Comment: @NervousDev first execute query on mysql work bench and check if it is giving any data from table.

Comment: It didn't fixed my problem BUT the reason is me not you. I have the data as a `string` that was send as d-m-y format with PHP. I looped my table and entered it again but I used the timestamp this time. I was able to achieve what I want it to.